# What information is the sender signing in the scriptsig?

Tags: transactions, input-script

In a transaction a sender must provide the digital signature to say that they own that transaction.

What information is the sender signing in the scriptSig?

I was thinking that It was:

- The particular input they would like to spend
- The address they would like to send it to?

Comment: I think you are mixing inputs with outputs. In the outputs there will be the addresses someone is sending values.

Comment: @OsiasJota Thanks for that. Do you know what is being signed?

Comment: please also have a look here https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22461/signrawtransaction-what-is-scriptpubkey-and-redeemscript-solved?rq=1 and here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8250/what-is-relation-between-scriptsig-and-scriptpubkey?rq=1 - this question has been answered already in the forum if you search for sign transaction. I vote to close as this is a possible duplicate.

Comment: short answer: the transaction without the sigscript is hashed, and this hash is signed. The steps are in the links. Another very good explanation is here: http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoins-hard-way-using-raw-bitcoin.html, and of course you need to read Andreas fantastic book "Mastering Bitcoin" :-)

Comment: Thanks @pebwindkraft , I've been trying to get through the book, sometimes I have burning questions and want to solidify my understanding as in most cases, I get something wrong. Thanks again

Comment: yup - in this exciting environment we all go through the same emotions ! :-)

Comment: @pebwindkraft I'm nearly finished learning the basics. You have helped me quite a lot in understanding bitcoin. If I may ask one more favour, could my question on forks, I am not quite sure what the person answering is talking about as the terminology is quite hard to grasp. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/72662/what-would-happen-if-two-miners-were-mining-two-blocks-with-two-different-set-of/72670?noredirect=1#comment84094_72670  Thanks for the help